# async.whilst - pausing between calls

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, while-loop, synchronization

I have a function which I need to call a number of time and instead of using a for loop I'm using async.whilst. But what I need is that the next call to function is not made before the previous call completes, which is not what's happening with async.whilst. Is there a way to implement this (I'm using setTimeout to pause between each call but it is not very clean).
Many thanks, C

Comment: Always shared code which will be better to know exact issue

Comment: I would try to rewrite the code so I could use `eachLimit`, but that depend of your code. Or recursion.

Answer (score 0):

i'd use the forever construct. Assuming your function's name is myFunction and accepts as parameter a callback:

```
var count = 0;
var limit = 10; // set as number of the execution of the function

async.forever(
    function(next) {
        myFunction(function () {  
          count++;
          if(count < limit) {
            next();
          } else {
            next(true);
          }
        })
    },
    function(ended) {
        // function calling iteration ended
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks very much - it seems to do it. NodeJS is a very different paradigm so it really takes a bit of time to get used to it ... C